# How to escape a string variable that might contain characters needing escaping (such as a $) in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

**Context**

I have this small logic to automate databases restore:

```
$sourceServer = "PROD"
$targetServer = "DEV"

$backupHistory = Get-DbaDbBackupHistory -SqlInstance $sourceServer -LastFull | Select-Object Path

foreach ($backup in $backupHistory) 
{
     $path = $($backup.Path)
     Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance $targetServer -Path $path
}
```

`$path` might contain a `$` character, for instance `\\Backups\Server$Instance\DB.bak`.

In these cases, when I use the `$path` variable as a parameter for the restore operation, the `$Instance` portion of the variable gets evaluated by PowerShell, which transforms it into an empty string, so, the value for my $path variable is now `\\Backups\Server\DB.bak`

**Question**

Is there any way to instruct PowerShell to use the string variable "as is" without evaluating it? I assume this would similar to escape the variable content, but I have not found a way to achieve this.

Comment: Where the `$backupHistory` comes from? Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. Read [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules).

Comment: Wrap the variable in single quotes: `'$path'`

Comment: PowerShell would only expand (interpolate) `$Instance` in `\\Backups\Server$Instance\DB.bak` if you passed this path _unquoted_ as a _direct, literal argument_ (to prevent expansion, _single_-quote the argument) . If you're using a _variable value_ as an argument, no quoting is required (the value will be used verbatim), which means that  either a broken value was assigned to the variable _or_ `Restore-DbaDatabase` unexpectedly performs string interpolation on its `-Path` argument.

Comment: @MisterSmith: That yields _verbatim_ `$path`, given that `'...'` strings are non-interpolating. Please see my previous comment.

Comment: I don't see how this could happen, unless you used double quotes instead of single quotes somewhere in the first place, like `$path = "$file"; get-content $path`

Comment: @js2010, the _value_ of a variable that is expanded inside `"..."` is _not_ also expanded; thus, if `$file` was a string to begin with, `"$file"` is a no-op.

Comment: Yeah this does not make sense as written. Either `Restore-DbaDatabase` is poorly behaved, or there's a missing `Invoke-Expression` somewhere in the code. I wonder if `Restore-DbaDatabase` is itself using `Invoke-Expression`.

Comment: Nope, dbatools does not seem to call `Invoke-Expression`. `Import-Module dbatools; Get-ChildItem Function: | Where-Object Source -eq 'dbatools' | Where-Object Definition -match 'Invoke-Expression'` returns no results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $someVar have value with powershell special characters, you should not care they can expand into some variables. Normally they will not.

```
$Computername = 'SuperServer'
$Temp = 'TempFolder'
$someVar = 'C:\$Temp\$Computername' # Note that I use single quotes
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $someVar # Will create C:\$Temp\$Computername , not C:\TempFolder\SuperServer
```

---

When you use string variable with special symbols in value, they remain just symbols. They are not expanded into variable values.

When you write string literals in single quotes, nothing is expanded.

When you write string literals in double quotes, everything is expanded.

```
$Var1 = 'Text'
$Var2 = 12

$ComboVar1 = '$Var1 $Var2' # => == "$Var1 $Var2"
$ComboVar2 = "$Var1 $Var2" # => == "Text 12"

Write-Host $ComboVar1 # => "$Var1 $Var2"
Write-Host $ComboVar2 # => "Text 12"
```

Please note that `$ComboVar2` is expanded when value is set, not when outpout is done!